# Drop down menu disappearing

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I created a drop down menu and added it to blogger. It is not working in Chrome or Safari. The problem is, the drop down menu appears when first rolled over, but disappears after the first sub menu item. This is not happening in Firefox or IE, only a problem in Safari and Chrome. Could it be a z-index issue? Any help is appreciated. I am adding the code below:

```
#navigation {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navigation li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index: 30;
}
#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-right: 0px;
    background: #00ddf5;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -89px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: -11px;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 20
}
#navigation li.over ul li {
        float: none;
        margin: 0px!important;
        top: 10px; 
}
#navigation li.over a {
    background: #a7f6ff;
}
#navigation li.over ul {
    padding: 0px!important;
    display: block;
    background: #00ddf5;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-right: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-top-right: 0px;
}
#navigation li.over ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    background: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#navigation li.over ul li a:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please put link of `www.jsfiddle.net` sample code with `html` codes. and use -moz- and -webkit- and without Prefix! for example border-radius: 0px;

Comment: Please include your HTML. A JSFiddle demonstrating the problem would help to increase the chances of finding an answer